# biconda channel error code 404 when building docker from dockerfile

Tags: docker

I havbe  dockerfile like this:

```
ARG UBUNTU_VER=18.04
ARG CONDA_VER=latest
ARG OS_TYPE=x86_64
ARG PY_VER=3.9
ARG PANDAS_VER=1.3
ARG BEDTOOLS_VER=2.3

FROM ubuntu:${UBUNTU_VER}
# Copy clinvar and parse_vcf.py to directory called /mydir/
COPY . /mydir/
# System packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq curl wget jq vim
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
# Use the above args 
ARG CONDA_VER
ARG OS_TYPE
# Install miniconda to /miniconda
RUN curl -LO "http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh"
RUN bash Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh -p /miniconda -b
RUN rm Miniconda3-${CONDA_VER}-Linux-${OS_TYPE}.sh
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:${PATH}
RUN conda update -y conda
RUN conda init

ARG PY_VER
ARG PANDAS_VER
ARG BEDTOOLS_VER
# Install packages from conda 
# RUN conda install -c anaconda -y python=${PY_VER}
# RUN conda install -c anaconda -y pandas=${PANDAS_VER} 
RUN conda config --add channels defaults && \
    conda config --add channels bioconda && \
    conda config --add channels conda-forge && \
    conda install bedtools
RUN conda config --show channels
RUN conda config --show-sources
```

I'm running into and error because the chaneel `bioconda` seems to not be available:

```
UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: bioconda
  channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

The channel is being added but the error continues.